# Adding volume to docker database breaks container

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

all

I've been working for some time with a Docker LEMP stack, and, up until now, have not had to use my MySQL portion. Today, when I added a volume to the compose file, it seems to have broken the container.

Without the volume attached, the container functions just as expected. However, when you add the volume to the stack, the task is repeatedly rejected. Because the container is automatically deleted and recreated, I was not able to pull any logs. Below is the MySQL portion of the LEMP stack...

```
mysql:
  image: 'mariadb'
  ports:
    - '3306:3306'
  volumes:
    - /mnt/sdb/Containers_Common/WWW/MySQL:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD={INSERT DB PASSWORD}
```

Providing context: The mount point is a network share established across all nodes using fstab. For testing, permissions have been set to 777.

Is there something I am missing here? Perhaps the MySQL socket needs to be mounted as well?

Running the container outside of the stack to get a look at the logs without them being destroyed produced these results:

```
2019-06-07T11:45:34.286323Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2019-06-07T11:45:34.286835Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) initializing of server in progress as process 30
2019-06-07T11:45:34.293509Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2019-06-07T11:45:34.293532Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] Newly created data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can safely remove it.
2019-06-07T11:45:34.293727Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-06-07T11:45:34.305548Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
6:45 root@Docker01 /mnt/sdb/Containers_Common/WWW/MySQL
```

Comment: What's in the volume?

Comment: What does the logs of `docker logs <container-name-or-id>` say? You should see more detailled information there why MySQL crashes.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The volume contains the persistent database files.

Comment: @Lion the container logs get destroyed when the service tries to spawn another instance. I'm going to try running the container outside the stack to get some logs...

Comment: Have you tried running `docker-compose up` attached (= without `-d` flag)?

Comment: @Lion that helped. I was able to fix the original problem. Thank you. Now I'm onto MySQL complaining about not being able to change the permissions of ca.pem

Answer (score 1):

Despite having 777 permissions, the MySQL server will not bind to a directory unless the owner is also changed to mysql:mysql

Comment: I dont have mysql user on host server, So how i can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've found something interesting:
the directory where your `docker-compose.yml` file is, or your `Dockerfile` must be seperated from your volume like so:

- Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml path: `/path/my_sql/docker-compose.yml`
- Volume used for mysql : `/path/mysql/data` (where data is a directory)